# using google recaptcha in local network

Tags: captcha, recaptcha

All, I was working with the google recaptcha in my website, But I found sometimes there exist 
error because my network is in bad status:

```
504 Proxy Timeout ( The connection timed out.  ) - https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LeMLL8SAAAAAIYgHs0VrUWMqrtozUXmq7LnvvJQ
```

So I wondered why recaptcha have to access the `api` hosting in the google.com.
Is there any ways to make it work in my local network which totally can not access any resource of the internet?thanks.

Comment: did you resolved this? I am in same place?

Comment: No, I doesn't have a solution to make it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396355/captcha-uses-offline-resources

Comment: I just asked and got this for reference. Did you tried this too?

Comment: In my environment, I can't replace it with other recaptcha component.So the solution your reference is not suitable for mine. thanks.