# Captcha uses offline resources

Tags: gwt, captcha, offline, recaptcha

I want to create a CAPTCHA verification of my application, my application is developed using GWT, which not use online resources.

I've tried with reCaptcha, but recaptcha have to access the api hosted in the google.com. Is there any ways to make it working in my local network which totally can not access any resource of the internet? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a local library like [SimpleCaptcha](http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/).

Here an article that explain how to use it with GWT: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/06/add-captcha-gwt-application.html

Comment: I will be back after going through this.

Comment: If you have issues with SimpleCaptcha library you create a new question.

Comment: End up with creating my own captcha image generator, and implement it on server side. Anyway tanks for your suggestion.